# MS ACCESS SQL How to UNION with Group By displaying Grand Total

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a query where I want to group by to show count of amount of each value in a filed and would like to UNION a second query which Should show Grand Total and Count of All items. Here is the abstract of my query.

```
SELECT a.[Field to Count], Count(a.[Field to Count]) as Count
FROM MyTable as a
Where a.[Some Field] = "Value1" AND a.[Some other Field] <> "Some value"
Group By a.[Field to Count]
UNION
SELECT "Grand Total", Count(*)
FROM MyTable as a
Where a.[Some Field] = "Value1" AND a.[Some other Field] <> "Some value"
Group By ?
```

What is want is this: 
Field to Count ========= Count
Value1 ================ Count of Value1
Value2 ================ Count of Value2
Value3 ================ Count of Value3
"Grand Total" ========= Count of All Field to Count Values

I know that without the Group By in the Second query it will not display anything so I know I need to use this. Basically something like "Group By *"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need `GROUP BY` in the second query or if that would even make sense.  Instead, just select the total table count:

```
SELECT t.label, t.count
FROM
(
    SELECT a.[Field to Count] AS label,
           COUNT(*) AS count,
           0 AS pos
    FROM MyTable as a
    WHERE a.[Some Field] = "Value1" AND a.[Some other Field] <> "Some value"
    GROUP BY a.[Field to Count]
    UNION
    SELECT "Grand Total" AS label,
           COUNT(*) AS count,
           1 AS pos
    FROM MyTable as a
    WHERE a.[Some Field] = "Value1" AND a.[Some other Field] <> "Some value"
) t
ORDER BY t.pos, t.label
```

Note that I added a computed column `pos` to each subquery in the `UNION` to be able to order the grand total last.  Note that in the outer query I don't actually select `pos` because we don't want it in the result set, we only want it for ordering.

Comment: Hey what does the lines: '0 AS pos' and '1 AS pos' do?

Comment: @RobertMazurowski I add a computed column to each subquery in the `UNION` so that your grand total will appear last.  This may have already been happening in your original query but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing Tim's a little as the outer select is not needed:

```
SELECT a.[Field to Count] AS label,
       COUNT(*) AS [count],
       0 AS pos
FROM MyTable as a
WHERE a.[Some Field] = "Value1" AND a.[Some other Field] <> "Some value"
GROUP BY a.[Field to Count]
UNION
SELECT "Grand Total" AS label,
       COUNT(*) AS [count],
       1 AS pos
FROM MyTable as a
WHERE a.[Some Field] = "Value1" AND a.[Some other Field] <> "Some value"
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Comment: Gustav Why do you put count in [] brackets?

Comment: The designer did that. I guess it is because it is a reserved word, though I believe the query will run without.

Comment: Gustav the ORDER BY part doesn't seem to work it says that a.pos is not part of the select statement.